# Login system with mysql detect the user id in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I created a form that has a login system connected to a MySQL database, information making a table that has 3 columns: User ID, username and email

Table representation:

```
    +---------+-------------+--------------------+
    | user_id |   username  |  email             |
    +---------+-------------+--------------------+
    |    1    |  test1      | email@domain.com   |
    |    2    |  test2      | user2@email.com    |
    +---------+-------------+--------------------+
```

When the form opens asks them to put a username and an email, I wondered if the application can verify that data set and detect the user ID, then put the user id in a textbox

EXAMPLE: I log in with the account "test1 , Put your email "email@domain.com".

I click on "Login" Then, consulting the user id account "test1" and put the user id in textbox "txtUserID".

My progress so far (Login Button) I just need the consultation of user id:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=Host;Port=3306; user id=Username;password=password; database=database_name"
    MySqlConnection.Open()

    Dim MyAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM xf_user WHERE username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND email='" & txtPassword.Text & "';"
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    command.Connection = MySqlConnection
    command.CommandText = sqlquery

    MyAdapter.SelectCommand = command
    Dim Mydata As MySqlDataReader
    Mydata = command.ExecuteReader

    If Mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
        Form4.Show()
    Else
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope it is possible , to note that not I have a lot of experience and can help me too if an expert.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
If Mydata.HasRows = 0 Then
    Form4.Show()
    txtUsername.Text=Mydata.Item(0)  //sample code 
Else
    Timer1.Start()
End If
```

Comment: @RiuChan In your case its equals to `Mydata.item` ,I corrected the Ans

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

```
MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=Host;Port=3306; user id=Username;password=password; database=database_name"
MySqlConnection.Open()

Dim sqlquery = "SELECT user_id FROM xf_user WHERE username='" & txtUsername.Text & "' AND email='" & txtPassword.Text & "';"
Dim command As New MySqlCommand
command.Connection = MySqlConnection
command.CommandText = sqlquery

Dim user_id as string = command.executescalar
```

`user_id` string contains the user id that equals username and email in table so you can put it in textbox like this:

```
TextBox1.Text = user_id
```

Comment: exactly what would this method?

Comment: i chnaged the sql to count rows in table and put result in string and then check if count =1 or not if yes Form4 will showup

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want, I updated the question for better understanding.